# Extend/ Modify Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android

Tags: android, sencha-touch, native

How is it possible to modify and extend the Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android (see http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android)? I want to add a Push functionality to the Android Project.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should use cordova(phonegap). With that, you'll get plugins to add push in your app. As far as I know, there's no way you can use PUSH with Sencha Touch itself. To work with Push you must have a device id. Sencha can not give you that (unless you manage to call functions inside your activity from javascript). Moreover, you need to have a broadcast receiver set up to listen to incoming push messages. Basically, there's bunch of to-do's involved in using Push, so you can not simply automate that job and let native packaging do it.

Modifying/extending sencha tools native packaging is not simply worth it considering time and efforts that would take (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://www.pubnub.com/ they have Javascript client to do listen to a queue and using that you can extecute whatever you want once message is pushed.